# Machine Learning associate solutions with issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

I'm new with ML.
I have basically a set of solutions, articles with title and steps, for common app issues in our departament.
I want to use ML to scan those solutions and train a model that based on user inputs like "In My pc microsoft word is not starting".
I'm still not sure if solution would be model triying to elaborate a series on steps based on the articles it has or maybe propose a set of articles.

My main concert is which algoritm I should use for each case.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think my guess is this is a challenging problem for machine learning (and any software) if the number of input questions is unbounded. Theoretically one could use NLP but seems very difficult based on the available data. If in contrast the input questions are constrained to e.g. a checklist a simple manual mapping could be used.